# Error Interpreting JPG file: Not a JPG file: starts with 0xff 0x28

Tags: image, jpeg, corruption

I do get the following error every time I try to open a JPG file : Not a JPG file: starts with 0xff 0x28

[image]

In the command line I do not seem to get any further hints or info about what is wrong:

```
$ file P1000868.JPG 
  P1000868.JPG: data

    $ identify P1000868.JPG
      identify: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0x28 `P1000868.JPG' @ 
      error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/322.
```

Would you please let me know how can I retrieve my image info?
I already tried changing the format to *.PNG, *.JPEG etc. and nothing helps. In fact the file was *.JPG and I could open it.

Comment: Then check if it's a valid file then using the obvious tools as imagemagick or even the official jpeg tools. Seems, that the magic-number / indicator is wrong (e.g. it's a bitmap, someone named it jpg and your tool is selecting it's decoding based on the suffix).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried changing the suffix but that does not help. I can actually try tools like imagemagick but I think its some known issue which could be solved without any tool in a programmatic way.

Comment: The issue is probably it's not a jpeg (and being interpreted as one). Either you bring in some tools to check that or not. That's your decision. No programming needed. You can start simple and drag that file into your browser (chrome is surprisingly robust and not selecting the decoder based on the file-suffix; although i doubt that's your browser).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A JPEG stream starts with an SOI marker FFD8. If your stream starts with FF28, it is not [valid] JPEG. There is no FF28 marker in JPEG so something is really screwed up with the data.